# RXJS, How to watch mouse and keyboard and do something when when none has been used for some time?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I need run a function if neither the mouse has moved, nor the keyboard has been touched for 1mn.

I tried the code below but doesn't seem to work.
How can I fix it?
Thank you for your help.

```
mouseEvent$ = fromEvent(document, 'mouseMove');
keyPress$ = fromEvent(document, 'keyup');

merge(
    this.mouseEvent$.pipe(startWith(null)).pipe(switchMap(() => timer(10000, 1000))),
    this.keyPress$.pipe(startWith(null)).pipe(switchMap(() => timer(10000, 1000))),
).subscribe(() => console.log("----));
```

Comment: You might take a look at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-idle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my take on this:

```js
 const mouseMove$ = fromEvent<MouseEvent>(document, 'mousemove');
 const keyPress$ = fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>(document, 'keyup');
 const mergeBothEvents = merge(keyPress$, mouseMove$);
 const interval$ = timer(60000);
 
 mergeBothEvents
     .pipe(
       startWith('initial'),
       switchMap(() => {
         return interval$;
       })
     )
     .subscribe(() => {
       console.log('60 seconds past');
       console.log('Perform function here');
     });
```

A bit of inside into what's happening in the code.

`fromEvent<MouseEvent>` used to capture the mouse movements.

`fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>` used to capture the keyboard key up click event.

`merge(keyPress$, mouse$)` is used to merge both the observables so that they can run in parallel.

`timer(60000)` is used to check the time of a minute before running the required function.

In `mergeBothEvents` we have used to more operators `startWith()` and `switchMap`

`startWith()` is used for the edge-case in which if the user doesn't do anything(mouse or keyboard) when he enters the page the `mergeBothEvents` event won't be emitted. Thanks @MrkSef to for pointing that out.

Finally `switchMap` is used to cancel the previous subscription of the event when the user moves the mouse or presses the keyboard so the timer restarts from 0th second.

Comment: This will only start the timer once `mergeBothEvents` emits. Once it emits, it will only start the next timer on the next emission.

Comment: @MrkSef, for learning purposes any update to this method that will ensure it works properly? or is it a lost cause? :D

Comment: @MrkSef, so this fails for the edge case that if the user doesn't move the mouse or press any key then `mergeBothEvents` won't emit, and hence the timer won't start, correct? Adding the `startWith('Initial')` fixes this edge case ?

Comment: This solution seems to work for my case. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to notice is that you typed mouseMove incorrectly.

Here's how I might do this:

```ts
merge(
  fromEvent(document, 'mousemove'),
  fromEvent(document, 'keyup')
).pipe(
  share(),
  startWith(null),
  debounceTime(60000),
  take(1),
  retry()
).subscribe(_ => console.log("1 Minute without input"));
```

Comment: can you please explain what is the use of share() and retry() in this solution?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. But it seems like with your solution, when the timeout occurs, you have to move the mouse or press a key to get the listener restart again